# Where can I find Webkit's CSS grammar files?

Tags: css, parsing, browser, webkit, grammar

Unlike HTML, CSS is a [**context free grammar**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar). Syntax grammar is usually described in [**BNF**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) or [**EBNF**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) notation.

According to [**Tali Garsiel**](http://taligarsiel.com/)'s articke [***How Browsers Work***](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/), WebKit uses [**Flex and Bison**](http://aquamentus.com/flex_bison.html) parser generators to create parsers automatically from CSS grammar files.

As Webkit is an open source project, I would expect these grammar files can be found somewhere in [**its source code**](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit). I haven't been able to find it, though. Can anyone help me out here?

---

**Note 1 :**

I'm **NOT** asking [**how browsers parse/render CSS**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605368/how-do-browsers-parse-render-css) / [**how browsers read and interpret CSS**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527800/how-do-browsers-read-and-interpret-css)!!

I know that already. In fact, it's explained pretty well in the aforementioned article [***How Browsers Work***](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/). So no, it's not a duplicate of that question.

What I'm looking for, is the specific CSS grammar files that Webkit uses to parse/render CSS, which I haven't been able to find anywhere.

---

**Note 2 :**

I'm also **NOT** asking anyone to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site... at all.

I'm just asking for where to find some files that Webkit uses (or used) for parsing CSS, because I've been unable to find them myself.

---

**Note 3 :**

I'm asking this because I'm looking for a convenient way to parse CSS. I want to base this approach on the way a browser parses CSS (more specifically = by analysing how it is parsed by Webkit browsers).

So yes, this question really is a programming question and totally on topic here at Stack Overflow.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do browsers parse/render CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605368/how-do-browsers-parse-render-css)

Comment: @Zeratops : It's not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605368/how-do-browsers-parse-render-css. It's a much more specific & much more technical question that hasn't been answered by that question and for which I can't find an answer anywhere else either.

Comment: I really don't understand why this question is getting so many downvotes or why it has been closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bison file (or at least, a version of it) is in the css directory as [CSSGrammar.y.in](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/Source/WebCore/css/CSSGrammar.y.in). That file is preprocessed and then run through `bison` using [a perl script](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/Source/WebCore/css/makegrammar.pl).

Apparently the flex scanner was rewritten in 2011/12; see this [webkit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=70107). The handbuilt scanner is part of [CSSParser.cpp](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/Source/WebCore/css/CSSParser.cpp).

By looking back in the git history, you could find older versions. For example, in the `safari-4-branch`, I found the following [bison](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/safari-4-branch/WebCore/css/CSSGrammar.y) and [flex](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/safari-4-branch/WebCore/css/tokenizer.flex) files.