# How do browsers process and apply CSS styles to DOM elements?

Tags: html, css, dom

Is there a consistent/universal order by which browsers apply CSS styles to DOM elements?

For example, the box model is: margin, border, padding and width.

Does a browser process CSS styles that are listed in the same order as the box-model faster than say CSS styles listed: width, padding, border and margin?

And, is there a standard/rule for the order in which ALL CSS styles are processed?

EDIT:
I am asking about the specific order in which Browsers apply specific CSS styles. Is this a universal standard or per browser? For example, does a *browser* have to apply z-index before it can apply a background-color?

Comment: there is no universal way how to apply the css-styles. The css spec defines HOW it has to look like in the end. How this is being achieved is pretty much up to the vendors. Nonetheless the styles are processed in the order the appear in the stylesheets.

Comment: What do you mean by the terms "process" and "styles"?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527800/how-do-browsers-read-and-interpret-css

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSS styles will always be applied from top to bottom, beginning with external stylesheets (in the order they are linked), then styles in the head of the document, then inline styles. Styles later in the hierarchy will overwrite styles that appear earlier.

EDIT: I need to amend my answer. Specificity plays a role as well. The more specifically defined a CSS selector is, the more precedence it takes. Selectors with equal specificity work the way I originally stated.

[ http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/ ]

EDIT #2: There is actually a good way to calculate the amount of specificity a given set of selectors has that can be found here: [ http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/ ]

(id selectors) `#foo` are worth 100
(class selectors) `.bar` are worth 10
(html selectors) `html/body/p/span/div/etc` are worth 1

`#foo span.bar`= 111
`html body p span` = 4
etc

Comment: I know that this is a post for 2012, but after reading this I thought it's extremely wild that specificity works that way and actually it doesn't. The edited answer is actually misleading, as it looks like it just adds points, when it's not exactly the case. (For example css selector div div div div div div div div div div p is not 11 points, but 0-0-11, which is below in terms of precedence to .bar, which would be 0-1-0). 

Tested it out and I found the information regarding it's functionality in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity