# How css style information is parsed?

Tags: html, css, browser, rendering

Rendering engine interprets html tags and attributes and creates DOM tree, where each node is the corresponding html tag and each node has the mapped properties corresponding to html attributes.

Who interprets CSS style information?

What is the representation(like DOM) of css style data, after parsing it?

*Note: JS engine(interpreter) has nothing to do with creation of DOM tree*

Comment: look into the document.styleSheets collection and it's properties.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527800/how-do-browsers-read-and-interpret-css Take a look here

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle