# When and how do browsers render <style> tag in <body>?

Tags: css, html

I noticed that if I place `<style>` inside `<body>` the css would be applied to all elements after and before `<style>` tag.

So it looks to me that the css is processed when the page is loaded, similar behavior to javascript document ready event. Am I right? And if that is the case in which order would multiple `<style>` tags be processed?

Comment: why not try yourself? and you're probably looking for `css specificity`

Comment: The CSS gets applied to all the elements in body, irrespective of page load. When the browser encounters `<link />` or `<style>`, the contents get applied for all the tags. If this is what you mean? Does it clear your question?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527800/how-do-browsers-read-and-interpret-css

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

In short, the answer to your question is: once a `<style>` tag is met inside `<body>` ***everything stops*** and the CSSOM is being rebuilt and re-applied to all existing rendered (painted) content.

Placing `<style>` tags inside `<body>` is considered bad practice because it can create [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content). But if your `<style>` tag only contains rules for elements placed after it in DOM, placing it in body is perfectly fine, as no FOUC can happen.

---

The render process of a page is quite complex. But, overly-simplified, here's what happens

1. `<head>` is read and CSSOM is built. All CSS is render blocking, unless explicitly specified otherwise by use of `@media` queries. The non-blocking CSS is still loaded, it's not entirely skipped.
2. DOM building and CSSOM building are ran in paralel, <del>but all `<script>` execution is deferred until CSSOM has been built (on `</head>` tag met), at which point all loaded `<script>`s are ran, blocking DOM building. JS can make changes to CSSOM at this point.</del>  *****
3. Placing `<style>` tags inside `<body>` interrupts everything (JS execution and DOM building), CSSOM is being updated and applied to the already rendered content, if any. Everything is resumed after.

***** On further testing it appears `<head>` parsing is single threaded. CSSOM building does block javascript execution but it's done is stages, as each `<link />` and `<style>` tags are met (a `<script>` placed after a `<link>` will only execute after the `<link />` was resolved and applied to CSSOM). `<script>` tags placed in between CSS resources are not deferred until all CSS resources in `<head>` are parsed, as I initially thought.
And, of course `js` can make changes to CSSOM at run time. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44375406/is-javascript-execution-deferred-until-cssom-is-built-or-not) I asked for more on how `js` execution is blocked by CSSOM building.

---

All the above apply to the normal loading, without considering `async`, which adds a whole new layer of complexity to it.

If you're interested in more details, I recommend going through the [Performance](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/) chapter of Web Fundamentals, provided by Google.

Comment: I'd be curious in finding out why my answer has been downvoted. The subject of this answer/question is one of great importance to me, I have read extensive materials on it and I'm always eager to know more. If anything I've stated is inaccurate, please let me know. I'm really, genuinely interested on this subject. Thank you in advance.

Comment: My answer was downvoted, too. Exactly the same moment I posted it.

Comment: Probably someone considering the question has too low quality to be answered. I can't imagine any other reason for downvoting my answer. But hey, this is [SO]. :) Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Andrei for explaining in details.

Comment: Not my downvote (yet), but this is wrong on at least one point. JS is run as it is encountered in the markup, except when marked as async or defer, not at the end.

Comment: @Alohci I'll retest. The last time I did it, it resulted in CSS inside <head> being parsed first and than JS being run. I will re-test. Do you have any resource/test that can shed some light on this particular matter? Also, note most of my tests are done in Webkit, I haven't tested much on Gecko or Trident.

Comment: Here's a simple idea. Before the first `<style>` add `<script>document.write("<!--")</script>` and after the `</style>` add `<script>document.write("-->")</script>`. The style element won't processed at all.

Comment: @Alohci: you're clearly right about `js` being run. The second <script> tag, however, is never interpreted as such. Should be replaced with `-->`. I'll reformulate my answer. But first I'll dust off all my old references and I'll go through everything that's been written on the subject since last I dug into it. Thank you.

Comment: @Alohci: Here's [a statement](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/adding-interactivity-with-javascript) from Google developers that seems to back up what I knew and stated in my answer: *the browser delays script execution and DOM construction until it has finished downloading and constructing the CSSOM*. Is it possible it's delayed, and when the script is ran, CSSOM is being re-built without the (now) commented rules and we don't get to see a FOUC because it all happens inside `<head>` and no actual elements make it to render?

Comment: I think that statement is somewhat misleading. I think it means that if the parser has *already encountered* a style element or stylesheet link, then on encountering the script element, the script will be blocked until those style rules have been downloaded and resolved. Otherwise, it either contradicts what that article says a few paragraphs earlier, or you would get deadlock between the styles and scripts with neither able to proceed.

Comment: @Alohci At this point I'm tempted to believe js exec is deferred until `</head>` is met, at which point CSSOM is complete and ***all*** js loaded so far is ran, which can change the CSSOM, in turn. When rendering begins CSSOM has already been altered. I know how to test this: I can make the commented `<style>` a `<link/>` pointing at a hanging resource (not resolving, without returning an error). If it hangs, js is deferred and I'm right. If it doesn't hang, it's not and you're right. Tricky setup, but I think it will be conclusive. I'm making ample changes to the answer anyway, to clarify.

Comment: @Alohci, see the updated answer and also the question I linked on the subject. Turns out you were right. `<head>` parsing is single threaded, and, thinking it through, it makes a lot of sense to be so. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

## Scope of CSS

A `style` element applies to the whole document, regardless of its position. It is applied as soon as it's loaded.

## Reason for putting style tags in `<body>`

Since every browser has a limited number of threads for downloading a page's files (like JS, CSS, images and asynchronously loaded HTML, JSON or XML), people tend to include CSS files at the end of the `body` element instead of the classic approach of including them in the `head` element. This way the rest of the page can be loaded and rendered, and the styling is applied last. You would go this way if your CSS is purely for the looks (i.e. no required element hiding) in order to improve the user experience.

## CSS files vs style rules in HTML

Including an external CSS file or putting the same rules in a `style` element have equivalent results regarding layout and styling. The external file has the downside of a little HTTP overhead, but the benefit of being cached for any further request. If your site consists of more than one page, you usually want to have one or more CSS files that are downloaded only once and re-used for most pages. In addition you can have page-specific rules in another file or within the HTML page.

Answer (score -6):

> So it looks to me that the css is processed when the page is loaded, similar behavior to javascript document ready event. Am I right?

No. The stylesheet is modified with the new CSS code when that code is added to the DOM. There's no delay until the rest of the DOM has finished loading. If there was you'd see a FOUC.

> which order would multiple `<style>` tags be processed?

The order they appear in. Then the [normal rules of the cascade](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade) apply.