# Why doesn't browser abort request to a stylesheet when the link element is removed?

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, browser

Consider the following HTML code:

```
<script>setTimeout(() => document.querySelector('link').remove(), 0);</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8080/test.php">
```

where `http://localhost:8080/test.php` is a link to a simple PHP script which just waits 5 seconds (`<?php sleep(5);`).

The script removes the `link` tag as expected, but browser doesn't abort the request to the stylesheet. This doesn't make sense, because when the request is complete, browser doesn't apply the styles anyway. Is this a browser bug, or is there an explanation for this behavior in the specification?

This happens in Chrome and Firefox; I didn't test other browsers.

Comment: Michal, how browser cancelation of the request should manifest itself? In HTTP there is no way for client to say to the server "stop executing this request on the server", all the client can do is just ignore the response.

Comment: @SergGr By "abort" I mean "close the connection with the server".

Comment: Michal, then I suspect that this is not implemented because it takes too much effort for so little result. [All features start out with minus 100 points](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericgu/2004/01/12/minus-100-points/)

Comment: @SergGr My question is mostly about what (if anything) does the specification say about.

Answer (score 0):

In a browser, the layout engine always parses the HTML from top to bottom, sequentially. However, the request to get CSS happens in parallel because CSS never changes the DOM Tree, there is nothing to worry.

> Since style sheets don't change the DOM tree, there is no reason to
>   wait for them and stop the document parsing
>   Resource: Read [Parsin Scripts > The order of processing scripts and style sheets](http://taligarsiel.com/Projects/howbrowserswork1.htm#CSS_parsing)

The main reason not to abort the CSS request is because it causes no harm. The effort to abort it would be much more painful.

However, note that:

> Webkit blocks scripts only when they try to access for certain style
>   properties that may be effected by unloaded style sheets.

[image: Image Credits - http://taligarsiel.com]
Image: WebKit Layout Engine. Credits - http://taligarsiel.com

Comment: "it causes no harm" – but it does: (1) it [blocks execution of scripts after it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44375406/3853934) and (2) if the style sheet is big, and you have a poor internet connection, it takes a long time and slows down other downloads.