# How do you reverse an iterator's flow?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, iterator, generator

Is it possible to access the previous value of an iterator, for example:

```
function* gen () {
   yield* [0,1,2,3]
}

var it = gen();

it.next().value // 0
it.next().value // 1
it.last().value // would be awesome if this was 0
```

This is strictly a curiosity question. I've been playing with generators lately and was wondering if anyone uses generators/iterators in this manner?

If so, I would love to see your solution. (Doesn't need to follow the above syntax) -Thanks

Comment: By `last` do you mean the previous value?

Comment: I meant the previous yield...Do you think I should reformat the code to make that more clear?

Comment: You cannot. The iterator protocol doesn't provide such an API.

Comment: @FelixKling But you can make a wrapper for generators; see my answer.

Comment: @MichałPerłakowski: Sure, one can always implement their own solution :)

Comment: @FelixKling Sorry for an off-topic comment, but could you take a look at [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44392831/3853934)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JS iterators only know one direction: forwards. Meaning, if you would want to use your custom iterator with a for-loop or the like, it would ignore your custom properties. You could however create your own [custom iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) for your own use only:

```
const obj = {
   values: [0,1,2,3],
   [Symbol.iterator]() {
     const values = this.values;
     const min = 0;
     const max = values.length - 1;

     let index = -1;

     return {
       next() {
        index = Math.min(index + 1, max);
        return { value: values[index], done: index >= max };
       },
       prev() {
        index = Math.max(index - 1, min);
        return { value: values[index], done: index <= min };
       }
     }
   }
}

var it = obj[Symbol.iterator]();

console.log(it.next().value); // 0
console.log(it.next().value); // 1
console.log(it.prev().value); // would be awesome if this was 0
console.log(it.prev().value); // would be awesome if this was 0
console.log(it.prev().value); // would be awesome if this was 0
console.log(it.next().value); // would be awesome if this was 1
```

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap the generator in a function that saves previous yields:

```js
const wrapGenerator = gen => (...args) => {
  const it = gen(...args);
  let previous, current;
  return {
    next: () => {
      const r = it.next();
      previous = current;
      current = r.value;
      return r;
    },
    previous: () => ({ value: previous })
  };
};

const gen = wrapGenerator(function * () {
  yield * [0, 1, 2, 3];
});

const it = gen();

console.log(it.next().value);
console.log(it.next().value);
console.log(it.previous().value);
```

I changed the function name to `previous` to avoid confusion (`last` could mean "the last item").

Comment: The OP used `last` as a reference to time, but it would be confused with *last item*. Why not call the method `prev` or `previous`?

Comment: @MajidFouladpour `prev` might lead to the expectation that it advances the generator in the opposite direction, which it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not generally possible. [Iterators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#The_iterator_protocol) can only be advanced, not reversed or anything else.

Of course you can write your own iterator wrapper that caches the last value and makes it accessible in whatever way you like.